# Replace dictionary inside array with another dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I am trying to update a value inside an array of dictionary but failing to do so.
This is how I am doing it :

```
    var latestServerData = [[String:AnyObject]]() // Global variable

in someFunction{
    print(latestServerData) 
    var dic1 = [String:AnyObject]()
    dic1 =latestServerData[4]
    dic1["isVisited"] = true as AnyObject
    print(dic1)
   latestServerData[4] = dic1
    print(latestServerData)
}
```

In `print(dic1)` I have correct data but its not getting replaced in `latestServerData` array. What I am doing wrong and what is the correct way. Any explanation with correct approach is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: self.latestServerData[4] ? I think it should be latestServerData[4]  mens not "self"?

Comment: @TofaaniKaanudo No! That didn't change anything. latestServerData declaration is global not in that particular function.

Comment: Can you print latestServerData in console and put here ?

Comment: Try self.latestServerData[4]["isVisited"] = true check it changes or not

Comment: @JonSnow No. It doesn't.

Comment: @TofaaniKaanudo it is a big response.

Comment: But you can put here as portion so we will help you based on it.

Comment: it should work !!! Please show your latestServerData before changes and after changes

Comment: Are you sure you have Bool there in value of **isVisited** you are saving   **true**, might be it is string like "true" ?

Comment: @JonSnow I am sorry, yes it is working. and yes it is a bool value. Can you write an answer with explanation and diff between two approaches. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JonSnow And if go present another view controller and dismiss it, will I get the updated latestServerData or the original one ?

Comment: @sharadchauhan You'll get the updated latestServerData

Comment: And instead of array of dictionaries use array of struct

Comment: @RajeshkumarR thanks. Tested and true.

Comment: @sharadchauhan I have confusion here ,   self.latestServerData[4]["isVisited"] = true is correctly working for you right ? :)

Comment: yes it is. @JonSnow

Comment: @sharadchauhan I have create demo and For me both approach is working fine !!! are you sure what you did is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me your code is working fine

```
var latestServerData = [
    ["name": "Amit", "age": "27", "rollno": 12,"isVisited":true],
    ["name": "Ananad", "age": "26", "rollno": 10,"isVisited":true],
    ["name": "Kashyap", "age": "25", "rollno": 11,"isVisited":true],
    ["name": "Raj", "age": "25", "rollno": 07,"isVisited":true],
    ["name": "Akshya", "age": "28", "rollno": 13,"isVisited":true]
] as [[String:AnyObject]]
```

**Here it is working for me**

```
var dic1 = [String:AnyObject]()
dic1 = latestServerData[4]
dic1["isVisited"] = false as AnyObject
latestServerData[4] = dic1
```

**It is also working solution**

```
latestServerData[0]["isVisited"] = false as AnyObject

print(latestServerData)
```

> ["name": Amit, "age": 27, "rollno": 12, "isVisited": 0], ["name": Ananad, "age": 26, "rollno": 10, "isVisited": 1], ["name": Kashyap, "age": 25, "rollno": 11, "isVisited": 1], ["name": Raj, "age": 25, "rollno": 7, "isVisited": 1], ["name": Akshya, "age": 28, "rollno": 13, "isVisited": 0]]

observe the First and Last object in array .  **isVisited": 0**

Comment: I still didn't get why my method is not working! Thanks for helping though.

Comment: You should use Any instead of AnyObject. AnyObject can only hold classes, not structures. All structures (including String, Double, Int, Dictionary) would be bridged to their counterparts like NSString, NSNumber and NSDictionary)

Comment: Btw you should also check your array count before trying to access its elements index using subscript.